# How to do query in Firestore for a range based on TimeStamp field

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a table of `events` in Firestore. These events a part of multiple fields, it have `startDate` and `endDate` fields that are `Timestamps`

I have to 3 types of queries to do related to this fields.

- Events that start after/equals at specific time [X]
- Events that ends before/equals at specific time [X]
- Events that in a range of time. [-]

For the last query, I tried something like:

```
Firebase.firestore.collection("events")
    .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("dateStart", dateStart)
    .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("dateEnd", dateEnd)
    .get()
    .addOnSuccessListener {
          if (it.isEmpty) {
             Logger.d("Empty")
          } else {
             Logger.d(it.documents)
          }
    }
```

(Where dateStart/dateEnd are `Date()`)

The problem is that firestore is launching an error:

```
All where filters other than whereEqualTo() must be on the same field. But you have filters on 'dateStart' and 'dateEnd'
```

And I'm stucked at this point. Is there a way to achieve this doing the queries?

Or I will have to query just for `greater` or `less` and then when I got the results filter in the app?